# problem involving fourier cosine series.

Tags: proof-verification, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

The first part of the problem is to obtain the fourier cosine series of period $2\pi$ Which represents $f$ on the domain $0\leq x\leq \pi$ 
where $$f(x)=\pi-2x,0\leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$$ and $$f(x)=0,\frac{\pi}{2}\leq x\leq\pi$$
My attempt:

The Fourier cosine series is given by $$f(x)=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\cos(nx)$$ where $$a_0=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)dx$$ $$a_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x)\cos(nx)dx$$

i calculated that $a_0=0$ and $$a_n=\frac{2}{\pi^2*n}$$ if $n$ is even and $0$ if n is odd. therefore my fourier cosine series was $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2}{\pi^2*n}\cos(nx)$$ is this correct?

Part (b) is that by letting $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ in the fourier series obtained evaluate the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}(1-\cos(\frac{n\pi}{2}))\cos(\frac{n\pi}{2})=-\frac{2}{2^2}-\frac{2}{6^2}-\frac{2}{10^2}-...$$ but i dont really know what to do, i was thinking that i would just write the series given  equal to the series calculated substituting x in? i ended up getting something like $$\frac{2\cos^{-1}(\frac{-2n}{\pi^2}-1)}{n}=\pi$$ but this cant be right surely.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes in the OP.  First, since $f(x)=0$ for $x\in[\pi/2,\pi]$ the Fourier coefficients are

$$a_n=\begin{cases}\frac2\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}(\pi-2x)\cos(nx)\,dx=\frac{4(1-\cos(n\pi/2))}{n^2\pi}&,n\ne 0\\\\
\frac\pi2&,n=0\tag 1
\end{cases}$$

Then, we have from $(1)$

$$\begin{align}
\pi-2x&= \frac\pi4 +\frac4\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1-\cos(n\pi/2))}{n^2}\,\cos(nx)\tag 2
\end{align}$$

Letting $x=\pi/2$ in $(2)$ yields

$$0= \frac{\pi}{4}+\frac4\pi \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1-\cos(n\pi/2))\cos(n\pi/2)}{n^2}$$

from which we deduce that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1-\cos(n\pi/2))\cos(n\pi/2)}{n^2}=-\frac{\pi^2}{16}$$

Comment: ahh briliant thank you i didnt realise that the limits were different, thank you.

Comment: Thank you and you're quite welcome.   It was a pleasure.  -Mark

Comment: i was wondering if you could update ur post to show the formulas you used for the coefficeients? i keep getting mixed up because on some sources they have different scalars in front of the intergrals, ones including $2\pi$ and $2l$ mainly for the $a_n$ and $b_n$ but these ones dont require them?

Comment: @Gibberish Equation $(1)$ of the post is an explicit expression for the coefficients.

Comment: ahh okay but if we was to find the b coefficients what would that formula be? it's been confusing me i keep getting mixed up and not all sources are saying the same stuff..

Comment: The coefficients on $\cos(nx)$ are given by $a_n=\frac1\pi \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin(nx)\,dx=\frac2\pi \int_0^\pi f(x)\cos(nx)\,dx$ since $f$ is extended as an even function on $[-\pi,\pi]$.  The coefficients on $\sin(nx)$ are given by $b_n=\frac1\pi \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin(nx)\,dx=0$ since $f$ is extended as an even function on $[-\pi,\pi]$.